# Constraint Langchain intermediate data format for the tool input

Tags: python, langchain

I follow the langchain instructions page to use tools
https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/tools/custom_tools

My code is below. However, it does not work as the instructions page since the LLM will not generate a numeric value for the age in the intermediate steps. How can I change the code so that it knows that before using the calculator, it has to pass in numbers and not strings?

```
def main():
     llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0)
     subclassing(llm)

def subclassing(llm):
    search = SerpAPIWrapper()
    llm_math_chain = LLMMathChain(llm=llm, verbose=True)

    class CustomSearchTool(BaseTool):
        name = "custom_search"
        description = "useful for when you need to answer questions about current events"

        def _run(
                self, query: str, run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
        ) -> str:
            """Use the tool."""
            return search.run(query)

        async def _arun(
                self, query: str, run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
        ) -> str:
            """Use the tool asynchronously."""
            raise NotImplementedError("custom_search does not support async")

    class CustomCalculatorTool(BaseTool):
        name = "Calculator"
        description = "useful for when you need to answer questions about math"
        args_schema: Type[BaseModel] = CalculatorInput
        llm_math_chain = LLMMathChain(llm=llm, verbose=True)

        def _run(
                self, query: str, run_manager: Optional[CallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
        ) -> str:
            """Use the tool."""
            return llm_math_chain.run(query)

        async def _arun(
                self, query: str, run_manager: Optional[AsyncCallbackManagerForToolRun] = None
        ) -> str:
            """Use the tool asynchronously."""
            raise NotImplementedError("Calculator does not support async")


    tools = [CustomSearchTool(), CustomCalculatorTool()]
    agent = initialize_agent(
        tools, llm, agent=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True
    )

    agent.run(
        "Who is Leo DiCaprio's girlfriend? What is her current age raised to the 0.43 power?"
    )
```

Prompt output where the issue happens

````
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
I need to find out who Leo DiCaprio's girlfriend is and then calculate her current age raised to the 0.43 power.
Action: custom_search
Action Input: "Leo DiCaprio's girlfriend"
Observation: Camila Morrone
Thought:Now that I know Leo DiCaprio's girlfriend is Camila Morrone, I can calculate her current age raised to the 0.43 power.
Action: Calculator
Action Input: (Camila Morrone's current age)^0.43

> Entering new LLMMathChain chain...
(Camila Morrone's current age)^0.43```text
age**0.43
...numexpr.evaluate("age**0.43")...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 743, in getArguments
    a = local_dict[name]
KeyError: 'age'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/langchain/chains/llm_math/base.py", line 80, in _evaluate_expression
    numexpr.evaluate(
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 819, in evaluate
    arguments = getArguments(names, local_dict, global_dict)
  File "/home/joe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numexpr/necompiler.py", line 745, in getArguments
    a = global_dict[name]
KeyError: 'age'
````